# LDAP authentication: why are users still visible on clients after deleting on server?

Tags: debian, openldap

I have setup OpenLDAP on a Debian 11 server, and configured a number of clients, mostly on Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04. There are some things I don't understand - well, many, but what I'm concerned about here is:

- When I create a new user on the server (using LDAP Account Manager), I can detect it immediately on all the clients; so far, so good.
- However, when I delete a user, it is still visible on the clients using `id someuser`, and `~someuser` still points to its home directory.

Why is that, and how can I fix this issue?

***Edit***

Inspired by *RonJon*'s comment, I checked some more things, and somehow things like password changes don't take effect anymore; that used to work before. And I looked for anything with `sss`; this is from one of the clients:

```
root@ceres:/etc/security# cd ../pam.d
root@ceres:/etc/pam.d# grep sss *
common-account:account  [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so 
common-auth:auth        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
common-password:#password       sufficient                      pam_sss.so use_authtok
common-session:session  optional                        pam_sss.so 
gdm-smartcard:auth    required        pam_sss.so allow_missing_name require_cert_auth
gdm-smartcard-sssd-exclusive:auth    required        pam_sss.so allow_missing_name require_cert_auth
gdm-smartcard-sssd-or-password:auth    sufficient      pam_sss.so allow_missing_name try_cert_auth
```

Comment: Is LDAP on the clients caching names "for performance"?

Comment: I don't think so - that would be if I used `sssd`, right?

Comment: I don't have any experience with LDAP.  It's just that "cached data" is the First Thing You Check in this kind of situation.  Kinda like how *They* tell you to clear your browser cache to fix any web problem...

Comment: 99.999% chance it's caching by the LDAP client daemon.  If your server is not using `sssd` as the LDAP client daemon, what is it using instead?  `nslcd`?  Something else?  That's where the caching is being done.

Comment: Try issuing `sssctl cache-expire` and see if that works. You can also control whether sssd uses a cache - `cache_credentials = False`. Ensure you are not running `nscd` and make sure it's caches have been wiped.